# How to assert elements of lists using Pytest?

Tags: python, list, pytest, assert

I'm writing Pytest and have two functions that return two lists. How to use *assert* and compare two unordered lists in Python 3.7? I would like to compare that each element(subnets) of  exists in expected_list and preferably use table driven tests

```
expected_list= ['subnet-123', 'subnet-456', 'subnet-789', 'subnet-000']

second_list= ['subnet-789', 'subnet-123', 'subnet-456', 'subnet-000']

def test_subnet_exist():
    expected_list = get_expected_list()
    second_list = get(second_list)
    for expected_list in second_list:
        assert second_list, "Subnet {} not found".format(subnet)
```

Because of the order of the list, it results in a 'AssertionError'. Using assert sorted is one way but I'm interested in knowing if it's possible to check if each element of second_list exists in expected_list

Comment: Are the elements unique and hashable? Then you can use `assert set(expected_list) == set(second_list)`

Comment: The elements are unique but are not ordered. I don't think set works for unordered elements

Comment: Why not sort just for the test? `assert sorted(expected_list) == sorted(second_list)`

Comment: why would sets not work for unordered elements? @CloudJedi

Answer (score 1):

Side-note: `get_expected_list()` and `get(second_list)` are kind of odd choices and don't run in the question as written.

If your elements aren't hashable, sortable, or don't have any methods other than equality defined then IIRC you can't do better than `O(n^2)`, so I'll assume hashability (for most reasonable objects that have equality defined you could also subclass and define a custom `__hash__(self)` method if necessary).

As long as your elements are hashable you can rely on builtin functions for testing membership.

```
def test_subnet_exists():
    assert set(get_expected_list()).issubset(get(second_list))
```

If you need a loop for any reason (e.g. for detailed logging as to which elements are missing) then you still probably want to use sets to make the process efficient.

```
def test_subnet_exists():
    # if hashability is impossible, leave this as `outer = get(second_list)`
    # and accept the O(n^2) performance impact
    outer = set(get(second_list))

    for item in get_expected_list():
        assert item in outer
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to loop over the list and we know they aren't unique (123 appears twice, and 789 twice in second, you could just iterate over them, right?

Just as an aside, it seems to be like the 'expected list' would be the key and you would want to instead be making sure the values in second list all appear in 'expected list' rather than vice versa.

```
expected_list= ['subnet-123', 'subnet-456', 'subnet-789', 'subnet-123', 'subnet-wrong']

second_list= ['subnet-789', 'subnet-123', 'subnet-456', 'subnet-789']

def test_subnet_exist():
    expected = expected_list
    second = second_list
    for element in expected:
        assert element in second, f"{element} not found"
    print ("All elements found")

test_subnet_exist()

>>>AssertionError: subnet-wrong not found
```

Comment: this ends up being practically an `O(n^2)` solution..

Comment: Yeah that's not good. Plus I left off the bit that I meant to include about asking whether the number of appearing elements had to be checked as well (i.e., do the two appearing "subnet-123"s invalidate since there is only a single "subnet-123" in second). Bad answer.